# Python mss ScreenShotError gdi32.GetDIBits() failed

Tags: python, numpy, bots, screenshot

```
import mss
import numpy as np
with mss.mss() as sct:
      area = [178, 110, 608, 182]
      region = {"top": area[0], "left": area[1], "width": area[2], "height": area[3]}

print(np.array(sct.grab(region)))
```

So, I was trying to code a bot with mss and sct. I keep getting a screenshot error and sct grab failing to run. Why is this happening? i have tried many variations of this same setup even one on a wider scale. I have no idea what is wrong. If anyone has any alternative libraries i can use please tell me.

I have tried following the directions in this [Got problem with mss: mss.exception.ScreenShotError: gdi32.GetDIBits() failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76546482/got-problem-with-mss-mss-exception-screenshoterror-gdi32-getdibits-failed) dicussion